# Turning off/on numbering when using mcode

Tags: numbering, code, matlab

I have an appendix with a full Matlab script, quoted verbatim, numbered and coloured as I want.

However, I want to quote about 10 lines of it as a figure in the body of my report, and since I will not quote any specific line numbers, they do not need to be included (the numbers also look nasty next to a table with a wrapped caption, where you get the 1 essentially sitting on the hyphen!)

At the moment, I have numbered turned on in the package options, and cannot seem to turn it off for the extract.

Alternatively, I could take the numbered out of the package options and then tell it to number the appendix.

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbered,breaklines=true]{mcode}

\begin{document}

some body
\begin{figure}[h]    
        \begin{lstlisting}[language=Matlab,breaklines=true]
    % loop over different monosaccharide in minimal media
    offset = 2;
    for j = 1:length(carbonSourceList)
    disp(['Current carbon source in media is: ', carbonSourceList{j}]);
    %fprintf('\n');
    lbColumn = (j - 1) * offset + 2;
    %ubColumn = (j - 1) * offset + 3;
    ubColumn = lbColumn + 1;
    currentFBAsettings = allFBAsettings(:, [1 lbColumn:ubColumn]);
    tempModel = batch_modify_flux_bounds(currentFBAsettings, origModel);
    \end{lstlisting}
    \label{Extract}  
    \caption{Extract from FBA Matlab script showing looping over different carbon sources} 
\end{figure} 
more body
\newpage
\appendix
\onecolumn
\small
\newpage
\section{MATLAB FBA Script, quoted verbatim}
%\lstinputlisting[language=Matlab,breaklines=true]{ATCC29149_FBA_all_v4_3.m}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Matlab,breaklines=true]
    % loop over different monosaccharide in minimal media
    offset = 2;
    for j = 1:length(carbonSourceList)
    disp(['Current carbon source in media is: ', carbonSourceList{j}]);
    %fprintf('\n');
    lbColumn = (j - 1) * offset + 2;
    %ubColumn = (j - 1) * offset + 3;
    ubColumn = lbColumn + 1;
    currentFBAsettings = allFBAsettings(:, [1 lbColumn:ubColumn]);
    tempModel = batch_modify_flux_bounds(currentFBAsettings, origModel);
    \end{lstlisting}
\label{FBAscript}
\end{document}
```

This produces both with numbers. When I tried putting numbered=False as a parameter, it started throwing up error messages about breaklines, which works when a 'numbered' parameter is not included in the \lstinputlisting options.

Comment: Hi. You should add some m code so that people can try to compile your code. In your code you need external files which are not available.

Comment: @ManuelKuehner Done. If you compile this (providing you have mcode.sty installed) you will get two pages. One which has on it a captioned figure with numbers, one with an appendix with the code numbered. I would like the figure to contain no numbers, but the appendix to have line numbers.

Comment: @ACrazyChemist You should have a look at the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package; it improves upon `mcode` in many ways. See [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891), for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.
I set up mcode without numbered selected.
I then found the set of commands that having numbered in the option ran and it looked like this:

```
\lstset{%
    numbersep=3mm, numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny, % number style
}
```

So I then just added this inside the \section within the appendix and the numbers were included.